# MonoDevelop on Ubuntu -- No compiler, no debugger, nothing... why?

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, ubuntu-11.04

I've tried to use MonoDevelop 2.4 and 2.6 with Ubuntu 11.04, but neither of them seems to actually provide any way of *running* the project. (As the picture shows, the Run, Step, and Debug items are disabled -- both on the toolbar and inside the menus.)

This is true for all project types I've seen so far -- C#, Python, etc...

But `mono-debugger` is installed. Is there some post-setup task that I need to do manually, for this to work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands/ProjectCommands.cs

Perhaps you haven't selected a 'Project'? Open up the Solution pad and click on the Test1 project (not the solution at the root of the tree, but the project just below it).

I'm just guessing here since I don't have Ubuntu and can't actually test anything.

Edit: actually, it looks like clicking on the Solution would work as well.

From looking at the code, another possibility is that you don't have a build target? Not sure how that would happen, but unless you only opened Main.cs and not actually Test1.sln, I don't know what to suggest.

When you opened the project, which file did you open? Test1.sln? Test1.csproj? Or Main.cs?

Comment: I couldn't believe my eyes, it was indeed the lack of having selected a project O__O! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for mono-mdb and more packages in synaptic, this may fix this issue. 
Don't remember exact names, Linux box at home...

Comment: I think I tried that with the older version and it didn't work, but I'll try it with 2.6 and see how it goes...

Comment: I've tried it yesterday at home and monodevelop worked fine (just updated to 11.10). A lot of other things broke down, though...

Comment: mdb is deprecated, the new soft debugger (sdb) support is built in

Answer (score 0):

Did you really open the *project*? It looks like you just opened Main.cs. It won't work that way.

Comment: Yes, it's a project called `Temp1`, as it says in the title bar. Just curious, what made you think it wasn't?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed the compilers (mcs etc)